# Is there an API for the Firebase Console?

Tags: api, firebase, firebase-console

I am playing with Firebase and I need to add multiple (iOS/Android) applications to my project for them to use the same database.
I can do it via the Firebase Console website, BUT can it be done via an API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no public API to create Firebase projects or applications in Firebase projects.

Comment: Maybe you know if it's planned ? I can't seem to find any information about this...

Comment: This is actually possible by using Firebase Management API https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/workflow_set-up-and-manage-project

Comment: Good call Karl. An API to create/manage applications in a project was indeed added since this question was asked/answered.